# jQuery Mobile links not working but are coded the same

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I have a jquery mobile site that I am working on and now some links work and some do not. The link for the top logo, the link "Bundle", and the "Legal Disclaimers" do not work but all of the link and coded the same. Anyone who can see what I have done wrong, please help. Thank you!

Here is the site http://m.gosatelliteinternet.com/

Comment: In href, just id page id e.g. `href="#page5"` JQM ignores hash in url. For _full site_ add `rel="external"` to anchor tag.

Comment: I found the issue, I was missing the closing </div>.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the protocoll in the links, so they are relative,

for example change

```
<a href="m.yoursite.com"></a>
```

to

```
<a href="http://m.yoursite.com"></a>
```

and it will work